# Issues With Tables and JSON data

Tags: php, html, json, api

I am getting data from a API which displays website templates.
The user can then proceed and create a website with those templates.

Part of my header is using two tables, using two different files; microheader.html and header.html

I call these in to my php file as follows

```
<html>
<head>

<title>Website Builder</title>
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="css.css">

</head>
<body>
<?php 

        $header = fopen("header.html", "r") or die("Unable to open file!");
        echo fread($header,filesize("header.html"));
        fclose($header);


        $microheader = fopen("microheader.html", "r") or die("Unable to open file!");
        echo fread($microheader,filesize("microheader.html"));
        fclose($microheader);


    $contents = file_get_contents('content.html'); 
    echo $contents;
    require('templates.php');
?>
</body>
</html>
```

Is there a way I should display a table straight after another?

There is nothing wrong with the tables. The headers are made up as tables.
When i display each table on there own, ie display one table and test, remove, display the other table, test, it is fine. But using table and then a table straight after leads to problems with sending the data to a website builder API i am using. My tables can be found below

The first table is:

```
<table class="micronav">
    <tr>
        <td>
            <p class="micronavp">Low Cost Business Websites, PPC &amp; SEO</p>
        </td>
    </tr>
</table>
```

The second table is

```
<table class="topnav">
    <tr>

        <td>
         <img alt ="" class="headerimg" src="https://www..co.uk/wp-content/uploads/2016/10/-2.png">
        </td>

        <td>
            <ul>
                <li><a href="https://www..co.uk/contact-us/">CONTACT</a></li>
                <li><a href="https://www..co.uk/my-account/">MY ACCOUNT</a></li>
                <li><a href="https://www..co.uk/portfolio-item/">BLOG</a></li>
                <li><a href="https://www..co.uk/digital-marketing-business-opportunities/">BUSINESS OPPORTUNITIES</a></li>
                <li class="dropdown">
                        <a href="#" class="dropbtn">LEAD GENERATION</a>
                        <div class="dropdown-content">
                              <a href="https://www..co.uk/product-category/small-business-seo/">Small Business SEO</a>
                              <a href="https://www..co.uk/product-category/pay-per-click-small-businesses/">Pay Per Click</a>
                              <a href="https://www..co.uk/product-category/email-marketing/">Email Marketing</a>
                              <a href="https://www..co.uk/product-category/b2b-mailing-lists/">B2B Mailing Lists</a>
                              <a href="https://www..co.uk/product-category/sms-marketing/">SMS Marketing</a>
                        </div>
                </li>       
                <li class="dropdown">
                        <a href="#" class="dropbtn">SMALL BUSINESS WEBSITES</a>
                            <div class="dropdown-content">
                              <a href="#">Do It Yourself</a>
                              <a href="https://www..co.uk/small-business-websites/">Website Design Services</a>

                            </div>
                </li>        
                <li><a href="https://.co.uk/">HOME</a></li>
                <li></li>   
            </ul>
        </td>
    </tr>
</table>
```

The templates.php file gets the JSON data and displays it, that works fine.

Is there something i am doing wrong with my tables and is there a way I can post a private message containing my JSON api data?

Thanks in advance

When I take one of the tables out it works and takes the user to an external website builder carrying over the Url get parameters but when i use two tables in two seperate html files straight after eachother in File Open php it doesnt work and takes the user to 
https:///DOMAIN.co.uk/websites/choose-your-website.php?template_id=1003040&email=test%40test.co.uk

Any help much appreciated